# Submit Button by Agreeing on Terms and Condition load new page

Tags: javascript, html, submit

I was reading over a few other submit button post on here but I need assistance with getting one to load a new page upon accepting the "terms and conditions"

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function checkForm(form)
  {
    if(!form.terms.checked) {
      alert("Please indicate that you accept the Terms and Conditions");
      form.terms.focus();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

</script>
```

For the HTML I have

```
<form onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
<p><input type="checkbox" name="terms"> I accept the <u>Terms and Conditions</u></p>
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Now when the select submit after checking a box I want it to direct them to a new page(the one they were trying to get to before being redirected to the terms of service page).

Comment: You'd want to redirect the user to the `referrer`; you can use `var referrerUrl = document.referrer` to get the referrer url, then use `window.location.replace(referrerUrl);` to redirect to the referrer url after the user has clicked submit. You might set a cookie to see if they set the checkbox or not when you redirect to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the advice provided by [noName](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45824515), I went with the following for this:

```
<form action="Games.html" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkCheckBox(this)">
I accept: <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="agree">
<input type="submit" value="Agree & Continue">
<input type="button" value="Decline" onclick="document.location.href='index.html'";>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change the url of the current page, you can use the following code:

```
document.location.href = "http://example.com";
```

However, if you would like to create a new page, you can use this code:

```
var win = window.open('http://example.com', '_blank');
  win.focus();
```

This example uses a pop-up window, which can be blocked by the browser, so I suggest using the first example.